# MacOS: iTunes switches to safe mode occasionally

Tags: macos, itunes

Once a week or so, this message pops up on my Macbook Pro:

[image]

why?  When I restart iTunes, iTunes seems happy again (for a time).

Answer (score 1):

Safe mode is (usually) triggered by holding  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  &  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  as you launch iTunes. It's a diagnostic mode for troubleshooting.

I can't imagine why it would do this alone, unless you have stuck keys… but you'd have very probably noticed that by now.

Comment: It doesn't happen while launching iTunes -- I think iTunes has been running for awhile when it happens.

Comment: hmm… in which case I've no idea I'm afraid. The only 'legitimate' way to trigger it is at launch… unless perhaps it's finding some old 32-bit plugin/visualiser & deciding it doesn't want it (wild left field guess).